# Can't make laravel 5.5 sessions work

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.5

I'm migrating a small crud from 5.2 to 5.5. My problem is that i can't the auth/sessions work. Once i log in, when i refresh or change section it redirect to the login page. I have a mistake in my code or i'm missing a command for start the session but i can't find it.

My HomeController

```
namespace desarrollosocialPrueba\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

My BeneficiarioController

```
use desarrollosocialPrueba\Http\Requests\BeneficiarioFormRequest;
use desarrollosocialPrueba\Beneficiario;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use DB;


class BeneficiarioController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        if (Auth::guest()){
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }        
    }

    public function index(Request $request){
        if ($request){ //si request existe voy a obteneer todos los registros de la db
            $query=trim($request->input('searchText')); //determina cual es el texto de busqueda para filtrar todas las categorias. searchText porque va a existir un objeto en un formulario listado donde se van a ingresar las categorias que quiero mostrar
            $beneficiarios=DB::table('beneficiario as b')
            ->select('b.altura','b.apellido','b.apellidoConyuge','b.barrio','b.beneficio1','b.beneficio2','b.beneficio3','b.beneficio4','b.beneficio5','b.calle','b.calle1','b.calle2','b.dni','b.dniConyuge','b.estadoCivil','b.fechaNacimiento','b.genero','b.hijos','b.ingresos','b.lugarNacimiento','b.nivelEducacion','b.nombre','b.nombreConyuge','b.observaciones','b.ocupacion','b.telFijo','b.telMovil')
            ->where ('b.dni','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')//busca por dni
            ->orwhere ('b.apellido','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')//o busca por apellido
            ->orderBy('b.dni','desc')//ordena de manera descendente
            ->paginate(15); //pagina de a 15 registros
            ;
            return view('personas.beneficiario.index',["beneficiarios"=>$beneficiarios,"searchText"=>$query]); //va a devolver la vista almacenada en personas/beneficiario  y se le pasan los parametros de los beneficiarios (las listadas de la variable) y texto de busqueda que tenemos en la variable query
        }
    }

    public function create(){
        //cuando se llame la url de create va a invocar al html que esta ubicado en personas/beneficiario/create
        return view("personas.beneficiario.create");

    }  

    public function store(BeneficiarioFormRequest $request){ //almacenar el objeto del modelo beneficiario en la tabla beneficiario de la db
        $beneficiario=new Beneficiario;
        $beneficiario->altura=$request->input('altura');
        $beneficiario->apellido=$request->input('apellido');
        $beneficiario->apellidoConyuge=$request->input('apellidoConyuge');
        $beneficiario->barrio=$request->input('barrio');
        $beneficiario->beneficio1=$request->input('beneficio1');
        $beneficiario->beneficio2=$request->input('beneficio2');
        $beneficiario->beneficio3=$request->input('beneficio3');
        $beneficiario->beneficio4=$request->input('beneficio4');
        $beneficiario->beneficio5=$request->input('beneficio5');
        $beneficiario->calle=$request->input('calle');
        $beneficiario->calle1=$request->input('calle1');
        $beneficiario->calle2=$request->input('calle2');
        $beneficiario->dni=$request->input('dni');
        $beneficiario->dniConyuge=$request->input('dniConyuge');
        $beneficiario->estadoCivil=$request->input('estadoCivil');
        $beneficiario->fechaNacimiento=$request->input('fechaNacimiento');
        $beneficiario->genero=$request->input('genero');
        $beneficiario->hijos=$request->input('hijos');
        $beneficiario->ingresos=$request->input('ingresos');
        $beneficiario->lugarNacimiento=$request->input('lugarNacimiento');
        $beneficiario->nivelEducacion=$request->input('nivelEducacion');
        $beneficiario->nombre=$request->input('nombre');
        $beneficiario->nombreConyuge=$request->input('nombreConyuge');
        $beneficiario->observaciones=$request->input('observaciones');
        $beneficiario->ocupacion=$request->input('ocupacion');
        $beneficiario->telMovil=$request->input('telMovil');
        $beneficiario->telFijo=$request->input('telFijo');
        $beneficiario->save(); //almacena el objeto beneficiario en la db
        return Redirect::to('personas/beneficiario');//redirecciona al listado de beneficiarios
    }

    public function show($id){
        return view("personas.beneficiario.show",["beneficiario"=>Beneficiario::findOrFail($id)]); //llama a la vista show pero envia el beneficiario definido para que la muestre y solo muestra esa con findOrShow
    }

    public function edit($id){
        return view("personas.beneficiario.edit",["beneficiario"=>Beneficiario::findOrFail($id)]); 
    }  //TAMPOCO SE SI VA A IMPLEMENTAR

    public function update(BeneficiarioFormRequest $request, $id){ //almaceno la categoria modificada
        $beneficiario=Beneficiario::findOrFail($id);
        $beneficiario->altura=$request->input('altura');
        $beneficiario->apellido=$request->input('apellido');
        $beneficiario->apellidoConyuge=$request->input('apellidoConyuge');
        $beneficiario->barrio=$request->input('barrio');
        $beneficiario->beneficio1=$request->input('beneficio1');
        $beneficiario->beneficio2=$request->input('beneficio2');
        $beneficiario->beneficio3=$request->input('beneficio3');
        $beneficiario->beneficio4=$request->input('beneficio4');
        $beneficiario->beneficio5=$request->input('beneficio5');
        $beneficiario->calle=$request->input('calle');
        $beneficiario->calle1=$request->input('calle1');
        $beneficiario->calle2=$request->input('calle2');
        $beneficiario->dni=$request->input('dni');
        $beneficiario->dniConyuge=$request->input('dniConyuge');
        $beneficiario->estadoCivil=$request->input('estadoCivil');
        $beneficiario->fechaNacimiento=$request->input('fechaNacimiento');
        $beneficiario->genero=$request->input('genero');
        $beneficiario->hijos=$request->input('hijos');
        $beneficiario->ingresos=$request->input('ingresos');
        $beneficiario->lugarNacimiento=$request->input('lugarNacimiento');
        $beneficiario->nivelEducacion=$request->input('nivelEducacion');
        $beneficiario->nombre=$request->input('nombre');
        $beneficiario->nombreConyuge=$request->input('nombreConyuge');
        $beneficiario->observaciones=$request->input('observaciones');
        $beneficiario->ocupacion=$request->input('ocupacion');
        $beneficiario->telMovil=$request->input('telMovil');
        $beneficiario->telFijo=$request->input('telFijo');
        $beneficiario->update(); //actualizo los datos de la categoria que recibe como parametro en el $id
        return Redirect::to('personas/beneficiario');
    }
    /*
    public function destroy($id){
        $beneficiario=Beneficiario::findOrFail($id);
        $beneficiario->condicion='0';
        $beneficiario->update();
        return Redirect::to('personas/beneficiario');
    } ¡¡¡¡¡NO SE SI SE VA A IMPLEMENTAR!!!!!
    */
}
```

The LoginController (almost standard)

```
namespace desarrollosocialPrueba\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use desarrollosocialPrueba\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/personas/beneficiario';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

My Routes

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('auth/login');
});

Route::resource('personas/beneficiario','BeneficiarioController');

//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
//Route::get('/{slug?}', 'HomeController@index');

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

It always redirect to login. I can't find the problem and i'm pretty sure that is super easy.

Sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina. If you can't understand something please let me know!!

Comment: Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade I know it's for 5.2 to 5.3 but it has important information about changes to the auth scaffolding.

Comment: yes, i read the article, but i can't find anything of sessions. maybe i explain myself wrong, i can make the auth, but i can't keep the sesssion running